# Double backslash prints the same in node

Tags: javascript, string, backslash

I want to create a directory string variable which is '.\app\src\algorithms' to use it in exec function in node on Windows Platform. 
However, it doesn not work properly even use double backslashes in the string.
Here is my try;

```
λ node
> directory =  '.\app\src\algorithms';
'.appsrcalgorithms'
> directory =  '.\\app\\src\\algorithms';
'.\\app\\src\\algorithms'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is fine. Internally it's stored as a double backlash because that's how escaping backslashes works in JS strings. The node REPL is showing you the actual value. When you use it, it should render correctly.

```
> directory = '.\\app\\src\\algorithms';
'.\\app\\src\\algorithms'
> console.log(directory)
.\app\src\algorithms
> exec('explorer.exe ' + directory); //works
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to handle platform independent work with path is using path module. E.g.

```
var path = require('path');
var directory = path.join('.', 'app', 'src', 'algorithms')
```